# Is external code in a call stack enough proof that my code is ok?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

Context:

I have a WPF application that is running in a host application using MEF. This host application is developed by another department where I work and all they provide to us are some assemblies and C# interfaces to which we use. My WPF application has a bootstrapper that is exported into the host application.

Problem:

The recurring problem that I'm having is that the UI elements of the WPF application all disappear when I run any of my event handlers on some button Click events. So naturally I put a breakpoint on the first line of one of the handlers, and debug. But all I see in the call stack is my line (where I placed the breakpoint), and the rest of the call stack has external code. So I'm trying to figure out if this is a problem in the host application, or something I introduced. The call stack only has calls to PresentationCore, WindowsBase, mscorlib, and to the host assembly, with one Native-to-Managed and one Managed-to-Native line.

Question:

Seeing that the call stack only has my one breakpoint line at the top, and the rest being the host assembly or Windows assemblies, is this enough for me to say that the problem is in the host assembly? Assuming its not any of the Windows assemblies. The UI elements disappear BEFORE my breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 1):

> All I see in the call stack is my line (where I placed the breakpoint), and the rest of the call stack has external code.

That is exactly what is supposed to happen in a callback: your code is on the top, with framework code directly below making the call into your code.

> Is this enough for me to say that the problem is in the host assembly?

No, for two reasons:

- Your code is responsible for bootstrapping itself for use with the external framework. If it fails to do so properly, problems in external code may become visible. Ideally, external code should catch these, and inform you that your setup was problematic, but the issue remains in your code even if the framework throws an exception rather than failing gracefully, and
- Your code may perform operations causing the external framework to get into an inconsistent state. Again, ideally the external framework should detect this, but the ultimate fix would be in your code.

> The UI elements disappear *before* my breakpoint is hit.

UI elements need a running program in order to redraw themselves. That is why debugging UI with breakpoints may get problematic. You may get better results by adding debug trace to your code, and running without breakpoints.